# AndroidX dependencies error on adding firebase to android

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat, androidx

I am working on an android project, When I tries to add firebase dependency to project following  Build error occurs. I have tried migrating to appCompat but didnt workded.

```
This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled. Set this property to true in the gradle.properties file and retry.The following AndroidX dependencies are detected: androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0, androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0, androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0, androidx.core:core:1.0.0, androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0, androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0, androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0, androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0, androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0, androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0, androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0, androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0, androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0, androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0, androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0, androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0, androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0, androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0, androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0, androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0, androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0, androidx.print:print:1.0.0
```

dependencies added without firebase are as follows:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
```

Please help to resolve above issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

The Android plugin uses the appropriate AndroidX library instead of a Support Library.

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

The Android plugin automatically migrates existing third-party libraries to use AndroidX by rewriting their binaries

Add both line in your ***gradle.properties*** file.

Then clean project and rebuild project.

May be your problem will be solved.
If not let me know.

You are currently using Android based library should be migrated to Androidx.

I suggest you migrate your project in Androidx.
You easily got more post How to migrate android to androidx my project.